# iOS 6.0 Apple LLVM Compiler 4.1 error

Tags: xcode, ios6, llvm

Updated Xcode to latest version and now getting a strange compiler error when I try to compile my existing project. I assume this is some build setting which needs changing but can't work out where.

```
Apple LLVM Compiler 4.1 error
clang: error: the clang compiler does not support '-fobjc-abi-version=0'
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [clang manpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/clang.1.html):

```
-fobjc-abi-version=version
           Select the Objective-C ABI version to use. Available versions are 1
           (legacy "fragile" ABI), 2 (non-fragile ABI 1), and 3 (non-fragile
           ABI 2).
```

From this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522053/what-is-a-non-fragile-abi):

> The non-fragile ABI refers to the ability to add instance variables to
>   a class without requiring recompilation of all subclasses.
>
> I.e. in v1 (there really aren't true versions of ObjC), if Apple were
>   to add an instance variable to, say, NSView (on Cocoa, 32 bit), then
>   every subclass of NSView (or subclass of subclass) would have to be
>   recompiled or they would blow up. v2 and v3 fix this.

So it looks to me like you want to remove the option and recompile everything.